# UIPickerView freezes UI when reloaded

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, uipickerview, freeze

The ui of my app freezes when the index of the UIPickerView gets to 1 or the number of elements is 2. Im really confused because this was working then all the sudden its broken. Ive done some research and found it may be something to do with a thread. Can someone help me solve the issue with the UIPickerView?

```
// class implements UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

     @IBOutlet weak var planetPickerView: UIView!
     var planetPicker: UIPickerView!
```

View did load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     //Other code not important 
     configurePlanetPicker()
}
```

UIPickerView implementation: (skyBalls is an array of classes whit various data as getters)

```
 func configurePlanetPicker() {
        planetPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: planetPickerView.frame.width, height: 70))
        planetPicker.delegate = self
        planetPicker.dataSource = self
        planetPicker.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-90 * (Double.pi/180)))
        planetPicker.frame = CGRect(x: -100, y: 0, width: planetPickerView.frame.width + 200, height: 70)
        planetPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = false
        planetPickerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pickerTapped))
        tap.delegate = self
        planetPicker.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        planetPickerView.addSubview(planetPicker)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int { return 1 }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {return skyBalls.count }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat { return 70 }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat { return 70 }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70))

        let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 10, width: 40, height: 40))
        image.image = UIImage(named: "\(skyBalls[row].getImage().split(separator: ".")[0])")
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        mainView.addSubview(image)

        let titleLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 70, height: 20))
        titleLbl.text = skyBalls[row].getName()
        titleLbl.textColor = .white
        titleLbl.textAlignment = .center
        titleLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        mainView.addSubview(titleLbl)

        mainView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * CGFloat((Double.pi/180)))
        return mainView
    }

    @objc func pickerTapped(tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if tapRecognizer.state == .ended {
            let rowHeight = planetPicker.rowSize(forComponent: 0).height
            let selectedRowFrame = planetPicker.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: (planetPicker.frame.height - rowHeight) / 2)
            let userTappedOnSelectedRow = selectedRowFrame.contains(tapRecognizer.location(in: planetPicker))
            if userTappedOnSelectedRow {
                let selectedRow = planetPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
                upgradePlanetName = skyBalls[selectedRow].getName()
                let settings = UIStoryboard(name: "PlanetUpgrade", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Upgrade") as! UpgradeViewController
                self.present(settings, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

I do reload the UIPickerView upon a button press that increases the size of the skyBalls array:

```
planetPicker.reloadAllComponents()
```

BUT the problem still occurs if `planetPicker.reloadAllComponents()` is entirely removed in all forms from the project.

I have tried restating my mac, iphone, and xcode, as well as deleting derived data. I cleaned the build folder and nothing seems to fix the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please highlight the line which has an issue? or what is the exact problem please share more about the issue.

Comment: @emrcftci sure thing. All of the buttons and views freeze when the app loads the second element in the picker view. It doesn’t seem to crash but just sit there as the phone gets hot. I’m not quite sure what line has the issue. I tried to comment out the viewForRow method and replace it with a standard array of numbers and the issue still happened

Comment: what is the detail of `.getName()` function?

Comment: @emrcftci it returns a string of the planet name. So the first index would be “Sun”.

Comment: please check @MoumenAlisawe 's answer

Comment: @emrcftci even with the entirety of the `planetPickerView.reloadComponents()`removed from the project it still freezes. It’s not just when it reloads.

Comment: if you've removed the reload line, when UI freezes? Maybe you should share more detail about your issue. I saw things you've done inside of the `viewForRow` function, maybe these causes your problem.

Comment: @emrcftci well the UI freezes either way if the reload line is there or not. I’ve tried removing the entire `viewForRow` method and replacing it with the `titleForRow` method to test is it was the views. I still had the same result. I have stored restarting every device, Xcode, and deleted all the derived data. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out that it wasn't the UIpickerView's fault at all. 
So after looking around I tried this:

> 1) Open "Breakpoint navigator"
>
> 2) tap '+' button and choose the "Exception Breakpoint" option

it then took me to the root of the problem witch was an array index out of bounds that for some reason wasn't crashing the app.

Answer (score 0):

when you have to update your view 
you must call `.reloadAllComponents()` always on the main thread  `DispatchQueue.main.async` should resolve the problem .

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.planetPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```